# How can I specify pyridine as a substituent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, aromatic-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds

You know how when you carry out a reaction with many compounds, when drawing the reactions you just draw a line at a right angle to the bond with a 'R' at the end (see image)?

[image: R]

Then you can specify what group R is in a table (eg: $\ce{OMe}$). However, if instead of adding a substituent to a benzene ring, you have pyridine? How can you specify it?

Answer (score 5):

The issue, I think, is to specify how the pyridine is connected. This means you have to identify which carbon on the pyridine ring is connected. This picture shows the numbering:

[image: pyridyl carbon numbering]

So, using your example the structure and names of the various possibilities would be (using connections on the 3-position of the benzonitrile ring as an example):

[image: example structures]

I'm sure you can generalise from this example.

Comment: There is another configuration where the nitrogen is connected to the first compound and a hydrogen is added to the para position in the pyridine ring.

Comment: You can draw out the substructure within the table, so it'll be a mix of text and drawn substituents.